# Protocol Buffers 2 and 3 in same C++ Linux application

Tags: c++, linker, protocol-buffers

I've got a C++ Linux application that already uses proto2.

It now needs to be able to parse a particular proto3 schema *as well*.

Unfortunately, upgrading the proto2 schema is not an option; neither is downgrading the proto3 one.

I'm aware the design smells, but this is what I've got to work with.

What's the least painful way of supporting both at the same time?

I understand the C++ PB libraries allow dynamically loading a `.proto` instead of using `protoc`. If I were to go down this path, would I have to completely change the proto2 bits as well? Can the proto2 and proto3 dynamic loaders coexist?

The other solution that comes to mind is doing the proto3 parsing in a shared object and dynamically linking it.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I just tried adding a file with protobuf 2 syntax to my protobuf 3 project and it worked without having to do anything special. What issue are you having?

Comment: @AlanBirtles i think you've pointed me in the right direction. The generated proto2 C++ files are coming from an external source and they were generated with an older version of protoc than the one I'm using. I didn't think proto2 and proto3 were compatible at all.

Answer (score 1):

@AlanBirtles made me realise there is no such incompatibility problem between proto2 and proto3. I just had to make sure all my generated `.pb.*` files were generated with the same version of `protoc`.